# Vector equation with cross product and unit vector

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Does anybody know how to solve the equation

$\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b} \times \hat{\mathbf{v}} = c \hat{\mathbf{v}},$

where $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are given real vectors, for the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf{v}}$ and the real number $c$?

Comment: $c$ is easy to find - take the scalar product of each side with $\hat{\mathbf{v}}$

Answer (score 0):

Write $\bf v$ as a linear combination of $\bf a$, $\bf b$ and $\bf a\times b$. If $\bf a$ and $\bf b$ are linearly independent, you get three independent equations for the unknown coefficients.

---

$$\bf v=\alpha {\bf a}+\beta{\bf b}+\gamma {\bf a \times b}$$
Plug it into the equation:
$${\bf a}+\alpha {\bf b}\times{\bf a}+\gamma{\bf a}|b|^2-\gamma({\bf a \cdot \bf b}){\bf b}=c(\alpha {\bf a}+\beta{\bf b}+\gamma {\bf a \times b})$$

Equation for the ${\bf a}$ component:
$$1+\gamma |b|^2=c\alpha$$
Equation for the ${\bf b}$ component:
$$-\gamma ({\bf a \cdot b})=c\beta$$
Equation for the ${\bf a\times b}$ component:
$$-\alpha=c\gamma$$
First and last equation combine to give:
$$\gamma=-\frac{1}{c^2+|b|^2}$$
$$\alpha=\frac{c}{c^2+|b|^2}$$
The second equation then gives:
$$\beta=\frac{({\bf a\cdot \bf b})/c}{c^2+|b|^2}$$

Now, this is a general solution of the above equation. Forcing the vector ${\bf v}$ to have unit length then gives you a condition for $c$. Try to do this yourself. Careful with expansion of all terms in ${\bf v \cdot v}$.

Answer (score 0):

We can write
$$
b \times \hat v =[b]_\times \hat v  = \pmatrix{0&-b_3&b_2\\b_3&0&-b_1\\-b_2&b_1&0} \hat v
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b} \times \hat{\mathbf{v}} = c \hat{\mathbf{v}} \implies\\
\mathbf{a} = -[\mathbf{b}]_\times \hat{\mathbf{v}} + cI\; \hat{\mathbf{v}} \implies\\
(cI - [\mathbf{b}]_\times) \hat{\mathbf{v}} = \mathbf{a} \implies\\
\pmatrix{c&b_3&-b_2\\-b_3&c&b_1\\b_2&-b_1&c} \hat {\mathbf v} = \mathbf{a}
$$
Happily, this matrix is invertible for all non-zero real $c$.

Comment: Is your matrix representation of the cross product applicable for every cross product ?

Comment: @Blue_Elephant what do you mean by "every cross product"?

Comment: It does not depend on the content of the $b$ vector ?

Comment: Yes, this procedure works for any $\mathbf b= (b_1,b_2,b_3)$